# Есть поле для ввода пользователя (<textarea>)

Tags: javascript

Когда пользователь начинает что-то вводить под этим полем появляется счетчик букв. Например,
в слове теперь:
т: 1
е: 2
п: 1
р: 1
ь: 1

Comment: @user2042869 Согласен, непонятно что автор хочет получить в результате своего вопроса и с чем у него проблема возникла. Но учить русский язык или нет - это личное дело каждого человека и к теме вопроса не относится. Все мы ошибаемся, кто чисто механически, кто по-незнанию. Мир не идеален.

Comment: Задача простая. Хотя бы начните и порассуждайте как это можно сделать, чтоб выявить основную проблему. В чем смысл, если вам просто тут напишут решение?

Answer (score 2):

```js
let text = document.getElementById("text");
let count = {};

text.oninput  = function (){
  let text = this.value;
  let length = text.length;
  let last_symbol = text.charAt(length - 1);
  
  if(count[last_symbol] === undefined){
    count[last_symbol] = 1;
  } else {
    count[last_symbol] += 1;
  }
  
  console.log(count);
};
```

```html
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

Comment: count[last_symbol] = 0; только с единички нужно начинать.

Comment: @AlexDevTime точняк, спасибо) сейчас поправлю